# PHP-Nginx timeout error

Tags: php, function, curl, nginx

I have a written PHP code that finds the title of a webpage and writes the title into the database.

Till now I had no problems but the list got expanded and more websites means more required time for php function. This causes my nginx web-server to run "Timeout" error.

I do not want to increase timeout setting from the nginx defaults since I don't want it to be abused by other users on other pages by sending long requests and keeping server busy.

Here is the code I'm using for getting title ;

```
    function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 15;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(strlen($data)>0){
$data = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data)); // supports line breaks inside <title>
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$data,$title); // ignore case

return $title[1]; }
```

The function works perfectly with few websites. Is there anyway I can make it dynamic? Like "Website 1 - Done" then "Website 2 - Done" then "Website 3 - Done" and follows like that so that nginx doesn't show timeout error?

Comment: You never specified what you want? You just mentioned what you don't want

Comment: you can try to add `request_terminate_timeout = <sec>` in your nginx conf.

Comment: I've specified after the code part that I want it something dynamic, like on games you send requests one by one or search engine submission websites where they submit your website one by one without getting runtime error

Comment: I would rather not add that type of line on my nginx conf since it might cause unwanted vulnerabilities.